# Horizontal scrolling of celltable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, scroll, celltable

In my GWT 2.4 app I'm having cell tables with >10 columns. I'm wondering how to add horizontal scrollbar to these tables because for some screen resolutions some columns are hidden.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use DataGrid instead of CellTable, or you can wrap your CellTable in a ScrollPanel.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin not works for me. I wrap celltable in scrollpanel.  Provided table-layout: fixed to celltable, vertical scroll coming but no horizontal  scroll

Comment: @zbyszek26104 not works for me. I wrap celltable in scrollpanel.  Provided table-layout: fixed to celltable, vertical scroll coming but no horizontal  scroll